SharePoint Document Library - Column Filters - Search Bar Not Available
I have a document library with a "Topics" column that contains various tags describing the document. The list of manually entered tags is now quite long. When clicking the column header, then selecting "Filter By" I only see a giant list of all of the tags.
Is there a way to display a search bar that can enable a quicker text search instead of scrolling through a giant list?
A search bar is available on the "Modified By" column, but not for any other columns.
See screen grabs for examples:



What is the column/data type of column you are using where search is not available?

The column type is "Choice"

Unfortunately, it is not possible to customize the display or functionality of "Filter by" pane in SharePoint online modern experience. This is a limitation of SharePoint.
Currently, Search bar in "Filter by" pane is available for few column types and not available for other column types.
Here is the list of supported/unsupported column types I have observed:
Search bar supported column types:

Single line of text
Person or Group

Search bar not supported column types:

Choice
Lookup
Date and Time
Number


I think this page for setting filter conditions cannot be changed, this is designed by SharePoint.
